# Bamboo on Windows Machine Unable to create docker container

Tags: docker, bamboo

I have been trying to create the docker container using bamboo but unable to configure it. I am new to bamboo as well as docker.

On the link [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/configuring-the-docker-task-in-bamboo-720411254.html) I have found out that we need to configure docker-machine via bamboo.

How to do that? How to create the task for the bamboo to create a docker image?